# How to prevent input event trigger when the data is changed outside the text input field in vue?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have a input field in my component which calls a method on @input like:

```
<q-input v-model="invoice_base">
<q-toggle v-model="overwrite" @input="updatePrices()" label="overwrite_the_input"/>
<q-input v-model="list_base" @input="updatePrices()" :disable="!overwrite">
```

But within the code there is a line where I have to modify the `list_base` itself.

```
updatePrices(){
    ...
    if(!this.overwrite){
        this.list_base = this.invoice_base;
    }
    ... here the list_base is used for other calculations
}
```

When the `overwrite` is toggled true then the `list_base` has to be modified and the other calculations still made. Here when I change it then the doSomething() method runs a second time because change of the variable triggers the (same) (@)input event as well (because it is synced). How can I prevent that from happening?

Comment: do you want to to increment that `number_data` when you leave the input?

Comment: No @BoussadjraBrahim there are some calculations within that method and as result the `number_data` may be modified. Not increment.

Comment: did you try out watch property?

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim no I didn't. But wouldn't the watcher trigger the `doSomething()` method itself when the `number_data` changes within the watcher?

Comment: your use case isn't clear enough, if you describe the real use case or sceario i could suggest a solution

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim I have edited and explained a litlle more

Comment: sorry i see your comment late, since you're using @input try to bind the `value` to `list_base` property and update inside the `updatePrices` method `<q-input :value="list_base" @input="updatePrices()" :disable="!overwrite">`

Comment: That did the trick @BoussadjraBrahim. I cahnged it as you said, will make a little more work but that is okay in order to archive this. Thank you for leading the way.